# How to push laravel notification via pusher beams ? and How can I add interests to my created notification so I can Listen in my react app?

Tags: laravel, push-notification, pusher

I've implemented pusher beams like this:

1. I've added credentials in `config/services.php`

```php
'pusher' => [
  'beams_instance_id' => '********',
  'beams_secret_key' => '*************',
],
```

2. I've created a new notification

```
class TestOne extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;

    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [PusherChannel::class , 'database'];
    }



    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
    //    event( new PostLiked($notifiable->id ,$this->message));
        return [
            'title' => $this->message->title,
            'content' => $this->message->content,
        ];
    }
    // notification type
    public function broadcastType()
{
    return 'users';
}
public function toPushNotification($notifiable)
    {
        return PusherMessage::create()
            ->platform('web')
            ->badge(1)
            ->sound('success')
            ->body("Your ac account was approved!");
    }


}
```

3. I've added Notifiable to User Model :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
  use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
```

How to specify the interest in my backend so I can listen to it in my react app and how to use beams debug console to make sure the Laravel notification is being fired?

Comment: if any one could send some link to some tutorial Which implement pusher beams in laravel and react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function toPushNotification($notifiable)
    {
        return PusherMessage::create()
            ->platform('web')
            ->badge(1)
            ->sound('success')
            ->body("Your ac account was approved!");
    }
```

While I was tracking this code , It seems that I had a **certificate issues problem** in my local environment.

So I moved to this way in connection to beams :

```
$beamsClient = new \Pusher\PushNotifications\PushNotifications(array(
        "instanceId" => "*********************************",
        "secretKey" => "***************",

    ), new GuzzleHTTP\Client(['verify' => false]));


    $publishResponse = $beamsClient->publishToUsers(
        array("user-001", "user-002", "1"),
        array("web" => array("notification" => array(
            "title" => "fofo",
            "body" => "Hello, World!",
            "deep_link" => "https://www.pusher.com",
        )),
        ));
```

Comment: Hi are you using laravel eco for this ? And with help of this we show the notification If tab is closed?